# Copy constructor doesn't copy references

Tags: c++

According to the topic [Pushing local objects into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723974/pushing-local-objects-into-a-list/27724120?noredirect=1#comment43860786_27724120)

The full class:

```
  class Invader
    {
    public:
        Invader(const Invader&other);
        Invader();
        ~Invader();
    public:
        void Init(InvaderTypes invadertype, CIw2DImage *AlienImage);
        void Update(float dt);
        void Render();
        void SetAlienImage(CIw2DImage *image){ mImageAlien = image; }

        void        setVisible(bool show)       { Visible = show; }
        bool        isVisible() const           { return Visible; }


        Iw2DSceneGraph::CSprite         *AlienSprite;
        Iw2DSceneGraph::CAtlas          *AlienAtals;
        CIw2DImage                      *mImageAlien;
        std::list<Bullet*>              *Bullets;
        CIwFMat2D                       Transform;              // Transform matrix

        bool                             Visible;                // Sprites visible state
        bool                             Canfire;
    };


Invader::Invader()
{

}

Invader::Invader(const Invader&other)
{       // Create EnemyTop atlas
    AlienAtals = new CAtlas();
    AlienSprite = new CSprite();

    *AlienAtals = *other.AlienAtals;
    *AlienSprite = *other.AlienSprite;
}

Invader::~Invader()
{
    for (std::list<Bullet*>::iterator it = Bullets->begin(); it != Bullets->end(); ++it)
        delete *it;

    delete Bullets;
    delete AlienAtals;
    delete AlienSprite;
}


void Invader::Init(InvaderTypes invadertype, CIw2DImage *AlienImage)
{
    if (invadertype == InvaderTypes::TOP_ALIEN)
    {
        //SetAlienImage(AlienImage);
        mImageAlien = AlienImage;
        // Create EnemyTop atlas
        int frame_w = (int)(mImageAlien->GetWidth() / 2);
        int frame_h = (int)(mImageAlien->GetHeight());
        AlienAtals = new CAtlas(frame_w, frame_h, 2, mImageAlien);
        AlienSprite = new CSprite();
        AlienSprite->m_X = 0;
        AlienSprite->m_Y = 0;
        AlienSprite->SetAtlas(AlienAtals);
        AlienSprite->m_W = (float)AlienAtals->GetFrameWidth();
        AlienSprite->m_H = (float)AlienAtals->GetFrameHeight();
        AlienSprite->m_AnchorX = 0.5;
        AlienSprite->SetAnimDuration(2);
    }
    else if (invadertype == InvaderTypes::MIDDLE_ALIEN)
    {

    }
    else if (invadertype == InvaderTypes::LAST_ALIEN)
    {

    }


    Visible = true;
    Bullets = new std::list<Bullet*>();
    Canfire = true;
}
```

I added the objects by doing:

```
  list<Invader> invaders;

    int spacing = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Invader invader;
        invader.Init(TOP_ALIEN, gameResources->getAlienImageTop());
        invader.AlienSprite->m_X = 50 + spacing;
        invaders.push_back(invader);
        spacing += 50;
    }
```

the usage: Right now it causes an access violation when accessing (it)

```
 for (list<Invader>::iterator it = invaders.begin(); it != invaders.end(); it++)
            {
                (it)->Update(FRAME_TIME);
                (it)->Render();
            }
```

You can see the result here in the following image:
  [image]

Comment: The `Invader` copy constructor is not invoked anywhere in this code. If something is uninitialized in `invader`, it's because either the default constructor or `Init()` doesn't initialize it.

Comment: @Barry The Init() does initialize it, I can see all pointers are initialized, before pushing the to the list.

Comment: Is this a debug build or release? A release build can sometimes confuse the debugger.

Comment: @andreahmed That doesn't change the fact that you haven't shown any code that uses the copy constructor. Meaning, what your copy constructor does is irrelevant here.

Comment: @RSahu sorry it was a typo

Comment: @andreahmed: not it wasn't, not according to your screenshot.

Comment: @Mat check the new screenshot, which has the same behaviour.

Comment: @andreahmed: still uses pointers

Comment: @Mat just uploaded now.

Comment: @andreahmed: now, is that a debug or release build, and do you actually have a problem when you run the code (outside the debugger)?

Comment: @Mat it's in debug. yeas when I try to iterate over the list, I get null pointers exception.

Comment: for (list<Invader>::iterator it = invaders.begin(); it != invaders.end(); it++)
  {
   (it)->Update(FRAME_TIME);
   (it)->Render();
  }
causes an access violation when accessing the (it)

Comment: @andreahmed: please edit your post so that it contains an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you're only showing small parts of it.

Comment: @Mat I have edited the post. Let me know if you need more information. That problem is very weird.

Comment: Did you miss the minimal part of the request?  Take your code.  Make a copy.  Eliminate stuff you doubt matters.  Test your problem still exists.  If not, back up and eliminate different parts.  If so, make a copy and repeat the process.  Continue until you still get the problem *and* you cannot eliminate any more code.  Simply posting more code, or posting oart of the code, does not help much.

Comment: @Mat changing list to vector, solved the problem completely and everything worked as expected!. that's very weird. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: No idea. Your copy constructor doesn't copy half the members, so anything goes, your code probably still doesn't work be you don't know it yet. Since you don't show code that we can use to verify your problem, it's nothing but guesses.

Answer (score 0):

First, during `Invader::Init())`, you provide a *copy of the pointer* to `AlienImage`. Then when you *copy* the object into the `std::list`, you don't copy that same pointer to the new object. Further, during `Invader::Invader(const Invader& other)`, you are not making a copy of `Invader::Bullets`. This leaves both the values uninitialized causing *Undefined Behavior* upon access (which probably occurs in `(it)->Update(FRAME_TYIME);` and/or `(it)->Render();` -- I can't verify since you didn't provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks so much. what's the solution to the first problem? I have no idea. I need to load the image once.

Comment: The first problem I mentioned was incorrect, I had misread one of your delete lines. But you still don't copy the pointer to the image over in the copy constructor which is your most probable source of undefined behavior (again, produce a MCVE as others have also requested)

Comment: how would I copy the image pointer? should I do that ?   *mImageAlien = *other.mImageAlien; in the copy ctr ?

Comment: Yes exactly. That copies the pointer, but not the object itself. That ensures that `mImageAlien` does not have a garbage value (unless you `delete mImageAlien` somewhere and don't update **all** pointers with the same value!)